# PHP session doesn't work in wamp5

Tags: php

I'm stuck up with php sessions its not working i jus checked for basic programs in session

ses.php

ses1.php

The above prog doesn't work. dont know prob wit prog or wamp server.
I have turned ON register_globals in php.ini
also i checked with session.save_path="c:/wamp/tmp"
session.save_handler= files.
pl suggest me to handle with session

thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, your question doesn't read very well. You should include some code, rather than the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating and closing the session?
Does the correct file path exist and is it writeable? (You are using windows, right?)

I would also recommend checking the php configuration from the WAMP admin screen to make sure the session information is correct. If you make any changes to the path, you have to restart the web server.

Example from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

```
<?php
// page1.php

session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #1';

$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
$_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
$_SESSION['time']     = time();

// Works if session cookie was accepted
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php">page 2</a>';

// Or maybe pass along the session id, if needed
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php?' . SID . '">page 2</a>';
?>
```

Page2.php

```
<?php
// page2.php

session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #2<br />';

echo $_SESSION['favcolor']; // green
echo $_SESSION['animal'];   // cat
echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']);

// You may want to use SID here, like we did in page1.php
echo '<br /><a href="page1.php">page 1</a>';
?>
```